# Visibility of databases in cloudbees?

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

I'm looking into using CloudBees for some application prototyping.  I am using free accounts right now, I am not paying any subscriptions at the moment.

The first step for me is to create a MySQL database to host my application's data.  I've done so (and it was pretty easy!).  I also use Liquibase to manage the database (I've started this work using local H2 databases for the pre-prototyping), and I've been able to construct everything as expected.

As part of checking whether liquibase created the tables, I brought up the MySQL database in NetBeans.  And, it did function well.  But I can also see other schemas as well as the schema I just created.  They're all innocently named (test, test_6hob).  But, I can see the tables and view their data.

My question is around the visibility of the data that's in the CloudBees database.  Is the database created for the free accounts viewable to other people connecting to the same machine?  Does this change if I use a paid account?  Or is it more the nature of how the database was created?  I can see other schemas (and their data) but I have no idea if other people can see mine?  Is there a permissions-aspect I need to ensure I set?  I've fairly ignorant with the inner-workings of MySQL.

While this is a prototype, were I to move into using CloudBees for production applications, I wouldn't want the data to be visible to anyone who happened to connect to the same database as my application.  It's entirely possible that I'm missing something in this new cloud world. :)

Thanks for any info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All CloudBees MySQL databases are secured separately (although will be in shared instances unless you have a dedicated server) - they are **not** readable by any other account **by default**.

However, it is possible for the database owner to grant access to users from other accounts on that same database server if you really wanted to - even though it makes very little sense to do so (and your special user configuration will be lost during a failover).

So this is what has happened for the test databases that you can see - the database owner has opened up security on those databases / tables.

Comment: OK, that makes complete sense.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I have an issue with updating mysql: when I update/insert my database/tables via the command line with mysql ... on the amazon ec2 host of cloudbees, I can do it but the update/insert is not visible in my app on <myapp><mydomain>.cloudbees.net. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Timo - Best to post this as a new question - we'd need more info on exactly what you were doing and expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably off topic but i'll bite anyway. The database data is private to your account. Actual hardware/vm's maybe shared but the data/database is not.

Comment: I'll take any comments, as I'm feeling this out for the first time. :)  I'd agree with you, but I could view the data in the other schema's tables.  I'm getting my head around there are shared machines, but I would have thought that I wouldn't be able to see data/schemas/tables created by other CloudBees accounts.  So, does that mean that other users/accounts connecting to the same machine (as it's shared) can see my data?

Comment: I wanted to ask something specific about Cloudbees.  When I clicked on it's forum link, it brought me here.  So, if there's a better location to ask Cloudbees' specific questions, I'm happy to go there.  It's just that their link brought me here...

Comment: What other schemas could you see? I would have thought it was just default/system schemas

Comment: Nothing meaningful to me.  But they weren't schemas like "INFORMATION_SCHEMA".  One had a hibernate_sequence table, and they had business model type names (car, address, account, passenger).  So, they're meaningful to someone (just not me).

Comment: Wierrddd- just tried it myself and there is another non system databases visible which I haven't seen before, test_243b, was emtpy. Unsure if this a bug or just intended behaviour. worth raising with cloudbees

Comment: Any suggestions how? :) As I mentioned, when I click on Forums, this is where it sends me... I'll look around